# Option of using spock lang specification test a Controller

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

just searching if spock lang specification can be used to test controllers that uses JDBC interface.   I am not doing RESTful API and not using Grails.  If Spock only supports grails then I guess Junit is another option.  I like how spock mocks classes behaviors and how its code simplicity for unit testing.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: You can import spock framework on your project and start using it. I work on a project using maven and java 8 and we use spock for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spock and Geb are totally independent of Grails. I never used Grails or even wrote Groovy application code in my whole life, I use Groovy only (and with pleasure) in order to write Spock and Geb tests for my Java applications or for any kind of web site.

FYI, Spock uses a JUnit runner itself, i.e. it builds upon JUnit and can be used as a full replacement for all your testing needs. It even comes with its own mocking capabilities, there is no need for Mockito or so anymore. If you had ever bothered to looked even briefly into the Spock documentation, you would have known, because none of those examples are related to Grails.

Comment: Yes saw the groovy documentation and doesn't have grails.  I prefer Spock since already uses JUnit runner and its more simpler. Thank you for your input!